# Generating wsdl using AXIS2 java2wsdl Tool

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis

I am trying to generate the a wsdl file for a simple java interface class shown below

```
package hellowebservice;

public interface hello {
   void sayHello(String s);
}
```

This is contained in hello.java.

I compile using

```
javac hello.java
```

Then run the tool:

```
~/Downloads/axis2-1.6.1/bin/java2wsdl.sh -cp "./" -cn hellowebservice.hello
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main"
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hellowebservice.hello
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a classpath issue. Make sure you're in the parent of hellowebservice folder when you run java2wsdl.sh.